# Make a Power BI report FitToWidth and full height

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI report embedded in my app. I have set the displayOption set to FitToWidth, which works, but the height of the report is very small.

I have not set any styling on the reportContainer div. If I explicitly set the height of #reportContainer to something like 800px, then the report height changes as expected. But what I want to be able to do, is have the report just be as big as it needs to be.

Comment: setting the height of the reportContainer to "height: calc((100vw - 60px) * 0.59);" gets around this issue (where 60px is the total margin either side of the report).

Comment: Thank you @Slicc you saved me a lot of time and pain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default height of iframe is 150px. Refer [iframe-mdn-webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#:%7E:text=height,is%20150.).

When you embed the report, the iframe takes up 100% of divs height. Therefore, we must define the height for the div container if we need to specify it for the report. (or else by default it will take 150px).

From the Power BI service, when you get the iframe, it specifies height of 541.25px. So, not sure how we get the report just be as big as it needs to be. Refer below snapshot.

[image].

Therefore, the user needs to choose the report height. Additionally, one can adjust the reportContainer height to the same as @slicc mentioned in the comment.